# Global property file for maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

I have seen many example saying that, fetch property values from external file in maven by using plugin is possible. I have tried the same but not succeed,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                 <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                 <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/sample.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

the file is present on the location, Did I miss anything ?

next questions is, I have parent repo referred in the above project, Is there any way to keep the property file over there? so I can refer in other project as well.

thanks in advance

Comment: If I have to guess by looking at the folder location `src/main/resources`, you expect to be able to use the properties inside your application. That's a no go, that plugin makes properties available only to the maven build.

Comment: that doesn’t work, checked, tried this  <files><relativePath>../sample.properties</relativePath></files>

Comment: Had another look and have to remind you that the properties this plugin loads can (only) be used for filtering resources. I.e. you can't use them in the same pom.xml for e.g. setting dependency versions, etc. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @Alex Can you please share an example

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the *properties-maven-plugin* is to filter (aka interpolate) application properties with external to the maven project values. Thus, such application properties can only be used in the application and not in the maven project. That is, you can't use the external property values inside the maven project model, e.g. for dependency versions.

As requested in comments, consider the following example project.

```
$ find . -type f
./external.properties
./pom.xml
./src/main/resources/app.properties

$ cat pom.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <prop>default</prop>
    </properties>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>app.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>external.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

$ cat src/main/resources/app.properties 
prop=${prop}

$ cat external.properties 
prop=not-default

$ mvn process-resources -q
$ cat target/classes/app.properties 
prop=not-default
```

Notice how the property `prop` defined as `default` changes its value to `non-default`. The external.properties file can be specified with both relative (as part of the project structure) and absolute paths (arbitrary location in or outside the project structure). Hope this helps.